# What are the correct steps to deploy a production laravel 5.2 app?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-5, web-deployment

I am using laravel 5.2 to develop app. 
As of now I am using `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` to deploy the test development app. 
I know that I have to change configuration file .env for production.
But itseams I can't use `php artisan serve` or `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` to deploy the app as production app.
I am using WAMP in my machine. Currently I placed my laravel app in `C:\wamp\www\laravel`.
What are the correct steps to deploy my laravel 5.2 app?

Comment: Deploy laravel in your localmachine or live server?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal How to deploy production app in local and in server too? We are using AWS.

Comment: In server its easy if it support composer i.e if its vps (virtual private server) or dedicate laravel hosting simply in the root dir place all ur file ... in command like make ur laravel open in 80 port of that public dir

Comment: @ujwaldhakal the routes are not working properly. if I use php artisan serve and route as "/admin/users/manage" it redirects to URl "localhost:8000/admin/users/manage" but if I navigate directly to localhost/laravel/admin/users/manage then URLs are not working properly

Comment: your ht access file pls

Comment: Please use Forge, there's nothing in the world easier.

https://forge.laravel.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php artisan serve` creates a local, development, very basic HTTP server and is **not** for production. It won't handle more than a handful of visits and will break quickly, and isn't secured in the way Apache or Nginx are.

Based on your directory path `C:\wamp\www\laravel`, I guess you are using a WAMP server? The A in WAMP is Apache - the web server you use *instead of* `php artisan serve`.

Setting up the site on a production server will vary based on your setup, but the general steps will look like:

- You should just put your project files straight into in your WAMP directory
- Run `composer install` to install the dependencies.
- Edit the database and other vars in your `.env` file.

Ensure that WAMP is running and the site is configured and you should should be good to go.

**If you don't have much server experience and just want to securely and simply host a Laravel app, I would strongly suggest checking our [Laravel Forge](http://forge.laravel.com) - it does everything and your site will be on the public Internet within 10 minutes.**